# Not sure why lambda fuction is not iterating according to loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
sel_ col10= ['ColumnA']
sel_col_new10= ['ColumnB']
for col, ncol in zip (sel_col10, sel_col_new10) :
    df_test[ncol] = df_test[col]. apply (lambda x: df_test [col] + df_test [ncol] if x== "Not Covered" else df test [ncol])
```

I was expecting to get it iterated through the whole column so that the formula applies to every cell of the column

Comment: `.apply`, when applied to a column (or Series), applies per element. It should therefore also return a single element, not a whole column. Unless you want to return a dataframe, but `df_test[ncol] = ...` indicates you want to return a Series.

Comment: Do you get an error? "not iterating" is not a very helpful indicator of the problem. Is there an error, are the results unexpected, is the result empty, something else?

Comment: Its checking the condition but concatenating only the first cell values to the whole column, its like its just taking the values from the first cell of the columns and not picking those in an iterative fation

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I think the below is the equivalent of what you are trying to achieve.

```
selection = df_test[col] == "Not Covered"
df_test.loc[selection, ncol] = df_test.loc[selection, col] + df_test.loc[selection, ncol]
```

(And I think there are even nicer ways to write this, with equivalent Pandas functionality as `numpy.where`, but I don't know that one by heart. Search for "Pandas where".)

It seems a bit weird that you use the same column for the selection as the one that you are adding to the new column. But that can work. I assume it means you go from "Not covered" to something like "Not covered - done".